# Web Service Reference to reportservice20xx.asmx on a distributed application

Tags: vb.net, web-services, visual-studio-2012, reporting-services, reference

I have an .Net webapplication which connects to a reporting web service.

In my development studio, I just add an webreference, then specify the path where the reporting server is installed and reportservice2010.asmx is found and ready for use.

But i do not know how to deal with it, after my application is compiled.
When  I would like to distribute it on lets say 100 different servers.

The path to reportservice2010.asmx may(and surely will) change.

Of course what will make my application corrupt.

Please help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you added the web reference, Visual Studio should also have added a new section to the application's configuration file.  That section specifies the environment-specific details of the web reference.

If, for any given target environment, the target address of the web reference changes then you can simply change the URL in the application's configuration file.

Comment: Thank you very much, and what about the credentials ? After addind reference VS asks for them. What happens if I change the path on a distributed Version ?

Comment: @JacobSiemaszko: Depending on how the authentication works there may be a few options, so you might have to Google around a bit for that.  One approach I've used before is to specify the security mechanism in the web reference config and specify the credentials in simple app settings (same config file), and then use those credentials to populate values in code when instantiating the web service object.  There's some information on that here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ad5ee8ed-0af0-422b-b960-3ee7e40a4bbb/pass-in-credentials-for-basic-authentication